# Does using an Angular service property directly in a component template good?

Tags: angular, data-binding, angular-services

After looking on the tour of houres demo by official angular documentation
link - https://stackblitz.com/angular/aygnjyjgero?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmessages%2Fmessages.component.html

I can see in messages.component.html that there are service property been used directly in the template. So does this means that it's ok to service property in the component template?

Comment: it's ok but not a coding standard as people are used to encapsulate the service logic into the component. It makes refactoring way easier if you need to change the implementation of your services.

Comment: the benefit i am getting is the reactivity though.